# time.clock() and the clock_gettime() accuracy - max error?

Tags: python, time

I am looking for specific values of accuracy (**not** resolution) in the Python function:

```
 time.clock()
```

and the C equivalent:

```
clock_gettime()
```

from the timespec structure. Both from time.h library.

I've only found the resolution (granularity) values in the documentation. All I need is the maximum time measurement error values for these two functions or at least an upper bound (e.g. the error won't be worse than 100ms). I'm running both programs on Linux.

Comment: I think this is highly dependent on your hardware setup

Comment: `time.clock()` uses C `clock()`, not `clock_gettime()`, though `clock()` may be implemented using `clock_gettime()`, see [`man 3 clock` on your platform](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/clock.3.html)